# How to get result back as JSON in looped query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am looping and getting results from multiple tables, and forming a result. How do I get the result back? All I am doing right now is logging it. Also, when I use array_append, it is converting the json into string.

This is the code I am running to get the data.

```
do
$$
    DECLARE
        sampleproductId   varchar;
        productIds        text[] := array [
            'abc1',
            'abc2'
            ];
        tId              varchar;
        DECLARE result  jsonb;
        DECLARE resultS jsonb[];
    begin
        FOREACH sampleproductId IN ARRAY productIds
            LOOP
                tId := (select id
                        from product.product
                        where uid = sampleproductId);
                result = (select row_to_json(row)
                           from (select accountid as "accountid", tId as "productUID", sampleproductId as "sampleproductId"
                                 from product.accountproductmap
                                 where productId = cast(tId as int)) row);
                if (result is not null) then
                    resultS = array_append(resultS, result);
                end if;
            END LOOP;
        RAISE NOTICE 'Result: %', resultS;
    end ;
$$;
```

And the result I am getting is

```
{"{\"accountid\": 8133, \"productUID\": \"1685\", \"sampleproductId\": \"abc1\"}","{\"accountid\": 9034, \"productUID\": \"2114\", \"sampleproductId\": \"abc2\"}"}
```

I am not sure why array_append is converting it into string before adding it, and not just keeping it as json.

I am looking to get it formatted like this

```
[
  { "accountid": 8133, "productUID": 1685, "sampleproductId": "abc1" },
  { "accountid": 9034, "productUID": 2114, "sampleproductId": "abc2" }
]
```

Comment: Use [`unnest`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-array.html) to do this with plain SQL. Also please describe, what do you mean by *converting it to string* and *keeping as json*. JSON is human-readable, so I see no difference between json and some text output in appropriate format

Comment: @astentx Thanks. I added the expected response.

Comment: @astentx I have never used unnest before. Where should I use it? I just tried select * from unnest(results) and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with plain SQL, because

- arrays are easily converted to tabular result with help of [unnest](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-array.html) function. So you can feed you input to query.
- SQL was developed to work with sets effectively and in declarative way (not by simple loops). That's why you should use `join` instead of loops.

To serialise data in json you can use `jsonb_agg`. So, this is the query:

> ```
> create table product
> as
> select *
> from (
> values
>   (1, 'abc1'),
>   (2, 'abc2'),
>   (3, 'def1'),
>   (4, 'def2')
> ) as t (id, uid)
> ```

> ```
> create table accountproductmap
> as
> select *
> from (values
>   (1, 123),
>   (2, 456),
>   (3, 789)
> ) as t(productid, accountid)
> ```

> ```
> with sp as (
> select *
> from unnest('{
>   abc1,
>   abc2,
>   abc\,3
> }'::varchar(10)[]
> ) sampleproductid
> )
> select jsonb_agg(
>   jsonb_build_object(
>     'accountid', a.accountid,
>     'productUID', p.id,
>     'sampleproductId', p.uid
> )) as q
> from sp
>   join product as p
>     on sp.sampleproductid = p.uid
>   join accountproductmap as a
>     on p.id = a.productid
> ```
>
> ```
> | q                                                                                                                                |
> | :------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | [{"accountid": 123, "productUID": 1, "sampleproductId": "abc1"}, {"accountid": 456, "productUID": 2, "sampleproductId": "abc2"}] |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=457ff69eaaec0d766d898b4599e514ef)*